# Winforms: Using the designer vs. generation by code

Tags: enterprise-architecture, winforms, designer

Due to a new job opportunity I am switching back from WPF to WinForms.

Currently I am playing around a little to get used to it.

Here are my main questions that arose:

- Should I use the designer in a professional environment? It feels somehow wrong to get that auto-generated clumsy event handlers... Otherwise generating all manually is hell of a work. But this seems more stable to me especially in combination with git.
- Do you leave your control logic in its cs file or do you capsule it in some kind of viewmodel/controller class?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I'd suggest you to use what is most comfortable and what you have more experience.

Comment: https://github.com/DavidRogersDev/WinformsMVP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do** use the visual designer to layout your GUI. Doing anything else is masochism.

**Don’t** put all of your code in the Form’s code behind.

**Do** use the Model-View-Presenter pattern. The form raises an event, which the presenter listens for, and reacts to by modifying the view and performing other business logic.

Comment: The key point here is Winforms is for UI and there should be a proper separation between code behind and business logic

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question, as long as the designer meets muy needs, I usually use it. If or when I want to do something more sophisticated (e.g. create or modify controls dynamically, or even initializing them according to complex rules), then I move to code. In any case, I choose the names ( both of controls and of event handlers) that I use in the code and don't just keep the auto generated ones.
Regarding the second question, for simple UI logic (e.g. enable/disable another control) I usually keep it in the code- behind cs file. But for anything further than this, you should use an MVC or MVP pattern. Implementing MVVM is not very feasible because binding in WinForms is pretty limited

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it is possible to implement MVVM in winforms. I created a proof of concept a few years back. https://github.com/rubberduck203/Rubberduck.Winforms